# Spark - Efficient way of querying rows (Pivot functionality)

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a below dataframe

```
|sno    |id             |value       |
--------|---------------|------------|
1       |Cnt_id         |1966        |
1       |Active_Ind     |FALSE       |
1       |Report_Status  |Active      |
1       |New_Ind        |FALSE       |
1       |State          |OA          |
2       |Cnt_id         |1223        |
2       |Active_Ind     |FALSE       |
2       |Report_Status  |Inactive    |
2       |New_Ind        |FALSE       |
2       |State          |MS          |
3       |Cnt_id         |112         |
3       |Active_Ind     |TRUE        |
3       |Report_Status  |Inactive    |
3       |New_Ind        |TRUE        |
3       |State          |US          |
--------------------------------------
```

I would like to query the data based on the values in the **id** column. Something like

`select * from table where Active_Ind='FALSE'`

Below is the expected output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------|
sno |Cnt_id |Active_Ind     |Report_Status  |New_Ind    |State |
---------------------------------------------------------------|
1   |1966   |FALSE          |Active         |FALSE      |OA    |
2   |1223   |FALSE          |Inactive       |FALSE      |MS    |
---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I understand this can be done through Pivoting queries, but looking for more efficient query which can be queried in a dynamic way as pivoting involves in hard-coding the values. is there any way where it can take input columns required and pivot in a dynamic manner.

Comment: Per SO guidelines please remove the images and post the data in text format (Don't waste time trying to format in nicely, we will do it for you)

Comment: Is there a reason for tagging your post with `scala`? Do you use notebooks that support different Spark APIs in different cells?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what's wrong with `df.groupBy("sno").pivot("id").agg(first("value"))` ?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz - Trying to solution this through scala (or spark sql). Hence tagged scala

Comment: @qaziqarta - Nothing particular. I was looking more effective way to handle this as I will be running on data that's around 202 billion (I know its strange but yes its a valid count for our use case :) ). So was just thinking on the lines of performance. Thanks for your input though it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of directly using `pivot` you could first filter the input dataset and then obtain distinct values for the pivot column on the filtered results. E.g.:

1. Group by `sno` and "collect-to-map" all `(id, value)` pairs, filtering by some particular `(id, value)` entry:

```
val df2 = (
    df
    .groupBy("sno")
    .agg(
        map_from_entries(
            collect_list(
                struct("id", "value")
            )
        ).as("id_val"))
    .filter("id_val.Active_Ind=='FALSE'"))
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|sno|id_val                                                                                         |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{Cnt_id -> 1966, Active_Ind -> FALSE, Report_Status -> Active, New_Ind -> FALSE, State -> OA}  |
|2  |{Cnt_id -> 1223, Active_Ind -> FALSE, Report_Status -> Inactive, New_Ind -> FALSE, State -> MS}|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

2. Hopefully, initial dataset would be significantly reduced by previous filter. On this reduced dataset, let's obtain all distinct `id` names:

```
val id_keys: Seq[String] = (
    df2
    .agg(
        flatten(
            collect_set(
                map_keys(col("id_val")
            )
        )
    ).as("id_columns"))
    .collect.head.getSeq(0))
```

3. With distinct `id` names we now can add all `id_val` map entries to final select statement:

```
val id_columns = id_keys.map(k => col("id_val").getItem(k).as(k))
df2.select(col("sno") +: id_columns:_*).show(false)
+---+------+----------+-------------+-------+-----+
|sno|Cnt_id|Active_Ind|Report_Status|New_Ind|State|
+---+------+----------+-------------+-------+-----+
|1  |1966  |FALSE     |Active       |FALSE  |OA   |
|2  |1223  |FALSE     |Inactive     |FALSE  |MS   |
+---+------+----------+-------------+-------+-----+
```